# How to set time via .htaccess for PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess

So I have been trying to set the correct time zone for my server. I dont have access to the PHP.ini file so I was working with. htaccess

On my local machine, 
php_value date.timezone "Europe/London" works perfectly.

But on the server online, I get 500 Internal Server Error.

The other way of doing it 
SetEnv TZ Europe/London does not work at all.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

For a complete list of supported time zones in PHP, please visit http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php.

To set the time zone, follow these steps:

Log in to your account using SSH.

Use a text editor to add the following line to the .htaccess file.

Replace Region/Zone with your own time zone:

```
php_value date.timezone 'Region/Zone'
```

Save the changes to the .htaccess file and exit the text editor.

To verify that the new setting is active, create a PHP test file that contains the following code in the same directory where the .htaccess file is located:

```
 <?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Load the test file in your web browser, and then search for the name of the directive.

The Local Value column should display the new setting that you specified in the .htaccess file.

Comment: I started my question by mentioning that this works only on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Open your .htaccess file then add :

```
SetEnv TZ 'Amerique/Port-au-Prince'
```